# セルの背景色を変更したい

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    @State var color = false
    var body: some View {
        List{…}.listBackground(color ? .white : .black)
        Toggle("テキスト", isOn: $color)
    }
}
```

としても、色が変更されません。
書き方が違うのでしょうか。

また、`.listRowBackground(color ? .white : .black))`としても変更されません。
`scrollContentBackground`を`hide`にしても変わりません。

セルの色は変えられないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.listRowBackground()`は、`List`全体に対してではなく、セルになる`View`個々に対して、付けてください。

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isBasicColor = true
    
    var body: some View {
        List { 
            Text("Blue")
                .listRowBackground(isBasicColor ? Color.blue : .red)
            Text("Red")
                .listRowBackground(isBasicColor ? Color.red : .white)
            Text("Yellow")
                .listRowBackground(isBasicColor ? Color.yellow : .blue)
        }
        .padding()
        Toggle("Cell colors", isOn: $isBasicColor)
    }
}
```

[image: Cell Color]

Comment: タイトルがおかしかったのかもしれません。Listの背景についても言っていました。.listBackgroundで変更されません。

Comment: 「SwiftUI List 背景色」などをキーワードにして、ネット検索すれば、比較的かんたんに情報が見つかりますね。例えば、[【SwiftUI】Listの背景色を変更する](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/swiftui-list-background-color/)など。

Comment: それも見て、実行したのですが一向に変わらないので質問させて頂きました。

Comment: この質問は、質問者さんであるあなたが、ベストアンサーをつけて、閉じてしまいましたので、これ以上コメント欄で継続するのは好ましくありません。新規に質問を立ててください。その際、質問の仕方は、マイナス評価をもらわないよう、よく工夫することをお願いします。